# Serialize List<double> into XML so each item of the list can be referenced by "GetAttribute("value")"

Tags: c#, xml

I'm a writing a program to create and edit a config file for another project made by an very inexperienced and idiotic developer (read: me a few years ago). Now I'm just slightly less inexperienced, although still pretty idiotic.

My issue is that the other project, which is already deployed with customers, manually reads through an XML file rather than just simply deserializing into an object. The way a List looks currently looks in the xml file:

```
<lut>
  <item value="0">
  <item value="1">
  <item value="2">
</lut>
```

The new class that I am using to serialize looks like this

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<double> lut = new List<double>();
}
```

when this serializes, for obvious reasons, it serializes to

```
<lut>
  <double>0</double>
  <double>1</double>
  <double>2</double>
</lut>
```

I would rather not mess with the code already deployed with the customer, so I was hoping there might be a way to custom serialize/deserialize this object such that the List looks like the former XML as opposed to the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution myself, I wrapped double in a class, and then used an attribute to make the actual value an XML Attribute. Might not be the most elegant:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<LUTElement> lut = new List<LUTElement>();
}
 
[XmlType(TypeName = "item")]
public class LUTElement
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now it serializes as desired. Thanks for being my rubber ducky, stackoverflow!